# Como inserir entidade com ID no Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Como inserir uma entidade com ID no Entity Framework 6.0? Ou seja, inserir com ID porque a tabela não o gera.
Por exemplo:

```
var last = _contexto.Area.AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
area.Id = last !=null ? last.Id + 1 : 1;

_contexto.Entry(area).State = EntityState.Added;
_contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Porém a seguinte exceção é lançada:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'SIPP.dbo.Area'; column does not allow nulls.

Comment: Está usando fluent api?

Comment: Não estou usando.

Comment: Pode postar o código que realiza o mapeamento? A entidade com Data Annotations ou o código do databasecontext caso tenha utilizado code first from database.

Comment: Também não estou usando Code First.

Comment: Você tem certeza que o `Id` objeto `area` está sendo preenchido? A exceção diz que o `Id` está nulo, o que me leva a crer que a condição para o seu `if` ocorrer não está sendo atingida, e para isso acontecer você provavelmente não tem dados na tabela Area.

Comment: Existe algum registro no banco de dados? se não o código correto seria: area.Id = last != null ? last.Id + 1: 1;

Comment: Existe o Id no objeto, isso que é o mais estranho ele dizer que tá nulo. E existe outros registros na tabela que foram inseridos manualmente.

Answer (score 2):

Decore o Id da `Area` com o seguinte:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Ao invés de usar:

```
_contexto.Entry(area).State = EntityState.Added;
```

Prefira:

```
_contexto.Area.Add(area);
```

Ao invés disso:

```
var last = _contexto.Area.AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
```

Prefira:

```
var last = _contexto.Area.Max(a => (int?)a.Id);
```